# How to scrape this image using JSOUP

Tags: java, web-scraping, download, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape this image using jsoup.

http://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/16627/114.0/compressed/s001.jpg?token=nYL050P9BCH5N_tE2hN4RuZXvCCAYkAr5pEQbApF6UU

I tried selecting the image tag using `getElementsByTag("img")`
but that doesn't return any elements.

Then, I tried downloading straight from this link but that returned an empty image.

Any solutions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download directly from this link:

```
http://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/16627/114.0/compressed/s001.jpg
```

In your code, when finding similar hyperlinks, remove everything after an image extension (`.jpg, .png,` ..). Such as this:

**`?token=nYL050P9BCH5N_tE2hN4RuZXvCCAYkAr5pEQbApF6UU`**

This second part is the issue here.

Comment: Cheers, I didn't realise the token was the problem. Thank you!!!!